# FPDF : Outputs php file insted of pdf file

Tags: php, image, pdf

i am using FPDF to output form data into PDF file.but when i click on submit button to post the data to generatepdf.php file , it outputs generatepdf.php file instead of right PDF file.below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<form action="generatepdf.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validation();" >

<input type="text" name="business_name" id="business_name" /></br>


<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" accept="image/*" ></br>
<input type="submit" value="generate" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**generatepdf.php**

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")|| ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["logo"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["logo"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
      if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["logo"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["logo"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
      else
      {
        $logo = date('dmYHis').$_FILES["logo"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $logo);
        $pdf=new FPDF();

        //set document properties
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Suraj Ahir');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Test');

        //set font for the entire document
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',20);
        $pdf->SetTextColor(50,60,100);

        //set up a page
        $pdf->AddPage('P');


        //insert an image and make it a link
        $image = 'D:\wamp\www\exportpdf\1.jpg';
        $pdf->Image($image,10,20,33,0,' ','http://www.fpdf.org/');


        $logoimage = "D:\wamp\www\\exportpdf\images\\".$logo;
        $pdf->Image($logoimage,10,220,25,25);

        //Output the document
        $name = date('dmYHis');
        $pdf->Output($name.'.pdf','I'); 
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to display `http://domain.com/file.pdf` instead `http://domain.com/generatepdf.php` in the browserbar?

Comment: yes , but it shows generatepdf.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the pdf file local on your server and then redirect the user to it.

So you have to edit your Output part of the code like this:

```
$pdf->Output($name.'.pdf','F'); // F is saving the file to the given filename
header('Location: ' . $name . '.pdf'); // redirect the user to the generated pdf file
```

This would be a soloution for your problem (maybe you have to adjust the code a bit).